# cannot change keyboard layout any longer

Tags: keyboard-layout

After a recent Ubuntu update and reboot, my keyboard map -- se -- has disappeared and the layout is frozen to us.

Here is the output from `setxkbmap`:

```
~% setxkbmap -v
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+se(nodeadkeys)+inet(evdev)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
Error loading new keyboard description
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it--my bad:

I had tried recently to change some definitions in the layout file (/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/se) without any effect, so I gave up. Obviously, I made a mistake which somehow disabled the whole chain of setting the layout properly. That was only activated by the reboot. Reverting the changes and rebooting brought the keyboard layout back.

I still do not understand how this all is connected and why it had this effect, but this issue is solved. Nothing to do with the Ubuntu update other than that I rebooted.